# How do I install fglrx on an AMD Kaveri machine?

Tags: lightdm, software-installation

I have recently built a Kaveri machine, but I'm having trouble getting the fglrx drivers up and running. I can install them, but the LightDM screen will simply be black.

The machine has an AMD A10-7850K APU and an Asus A88XM-PLUS motherboard. I have done tests using both Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04. In the end I don't mind using either.

I have tried the following:

- Install the regular fglrx-updates -> No result
- Install the xorg-edgers ppa -> No result
- Manually install the official AMD beta version via [this cchtml guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Saucy_Installation_Guide) -> No result
- Remove all kernels and install the 3.12 kernel from the [mainline ppa](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/), and install the official AMD beta version against that kernel -> No result

It must be possible, because [Phoronix has tested fglrx against the exact same APU on a slightly different motherboard of the same series](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd_kaveri_ulinux&num=4), except they didn't provide any instructions on the installation bit.

Any help is welcome, as the internet is currently a barren desert when it comes to AMD's new APU on Linux.

Comment: what is the content of the log files? `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`?

Comment: You have an exact the same setup as I do. And sadly [I have a follow-up question](http://askubuntu.com/q/432096/256651) - maybe you have seen problem like mine when you experimented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. AMD released their Catalyst 14.1 driver with A10-7850K support for Linux. Note that THIS IS A BETA DRIVER, AND IS THEREFORE EXPERIMENTAL. The performance I've got out of it is okay, though. Trine 2, Dota 2, Minecraft (OpenJDK 7), Europa Universalis IV and Guns of Icarus Online all ran reasonably well on 1920x1080 with medium/high settings.

Instructions:

1. Download [the driver from AMD](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx).
2. Unzip the file.
3. Make the new file executable. `sudo chmod u+x amd-driver*.run` should do the trick.
4. Install the prerequisites: `sudo apt-get install cdbs dh-make dkms execstack dh-modaliases linux-headers-generic libqtgui4 lib32gcc1`
5. Create .deb files from the installer: `sudo ./amd-driver*.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/saucy`  Replace Ubuntu/saucy with your version if applicable. AMD says it's compatible with Ubuntu 12.04 as well, so you'd put `--buildpkg Ubuntu/precise` at the end.
6. Do the actual installation bit: `sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb`  This installs multiple .debs.
7. Optional-ish, initialise the xorg.conf file after restarting your computer: `sudo amdconfig --initial -f`

And that's that.

Comment: I tried this today and needed to add `xserver-xorg-dev` to the list of packages in step 4 to get it to work all right.