# How to turn off proprietary ATI drivers using Recovery Mode?

Tags: ati

I have setup just like [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/409171/256651) - AMD A10-7850K APU and an Asus A88XM-PLUS motherboard. Instruction by Ruben Bakker tells me how to install what I need, but it does not tell me how to clean up my system after a failed attempt made on my own.

I installed drivers using Additional Drivers manager. Restarted, and now every time I boot all I can get is a black screen. Keyboard and mouse are trapped and I can't switch to text console, and so on. I can boot to recovery mode but what do I do there? In the old times when I was using Gentoo I would just edit `xorg.conf` to switch to an open driver, but I can't find anything like that in my Ubuntu. And I'm sure there is no text-based version of Additional Drivers manager.

Comment: Note - [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/68306/256651)'s answer tells to `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` but I can't find that file in my setup, so there is something different in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the correct answer, but I'll have a go. [Try this page](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Saucy_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx). Extracted instructions:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
```

followed by the following for the sake of making sure all is clean:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo rm -f /etc/ati
```

That should remove all previous FGLRX drivers you had. Now you're back to the fresh Ubuntu graphics setup. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409171/how-do-i-install-fglrx-on-an-amd-kaveri-machine?noredirect=1#comment561192_409171) provides an answer on how to get FGLRX working with Kaveri, but you had already seen that question.

Comment: Except for the fact I didn't have /etc/X11/xorg.conf at all (as mentioned above) it worked perfectly. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the proprietary drivers from the official repositories run

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx\*
```

in recovery mode and then reboot. This helped me revert a problematic `fglrx` installation in Ubuntu 12.04 on a PC with an AMD Radeon HD 7770 graphics card.

Comment: Downvote isn't from me, but I admit - your answer did not work. First, `\` is bad idea. Second, this command itself was not enough.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear it didn't work for you. What do you mean by "``"? What issues remained once you ran the command and rebooted?

Comment: Argh, I meant `\\` but forgot to escape backslash, and code ticks seems not work for me as I expected.

Comment: I see. The reason I used `\*` is because it's mandatory in `zsh` (at least as I have it configured) and it is also accepted by `bash`. Why is using it a bad idea? Boy, writing this combination of symbols is hard.